# Tizen TV SDK: Tizen object missing tvchannel field

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm working on developing a Tizen TV Web Application. I'm using the Tizen SDK and trying to simply get the current channel like so:

`var channel = tizen.tvchannel.getCurrentChannel();`

However, this tvchannel field appears to be missing from the 'tizen' object when we log the object itself. According to the API specification (https://www.tizen.org/zh-hans/tv/web_device_api?langredirect=1) this field is supposed to be there, however all that the object has pertaining to TV functionality is the TV Input Device and TV Audio Control fields. Any information on this topic would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include correct privileges? I guess that for the TV channel you should add tv.channel privilege..

Comment: Yes that privilege is included. Any other tips?